# How do you wait for a promise using protractor and Chai?

Tags: protractor, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm trying to wait for a promise resolution using Cucumber, Chai, and Protractor. Is there a way using Chai to wait for something (like a pageload) to occur before sending the callback?

I want something like:

```
browser.get(url).then(callback)
```

which I thought would be in Chai:

```
browser.get(url).should.be.fulfilled.and.notify(callback);
```

although when I do that, I'm just getting a timeout, but I see the page has loaded. 
I already have it setup with:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;
var should = chai.should;
```

I don't want to check for something, I just want to make sure the page loads. From what I've seen most people just do:

```
browser.get(url);
callback();
```

and only use an `assert` or `expect` in a Gherkins Then clause, but I want to wait for the page to load in a Given or When.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand with your question is you want the asynchronous `Given, When, Then's` in `CucumberJS` to behave as synchronous execution, So that once your step with `browser.get(url)` is completed then the next step definition is executed. If that is what your question is then **Yes** we can do that-

You need to either `return` a promise or use the `done` callback in your step definitions. Otherwise cucumber doesn't know when your asynchronous actions are complete.

I prefer to `return` promises when I am performing some actions on the results with .then function and use `.done` callback function when I am not, Also you don't need `callbacks` now CucumberJS supports `promises`. So your step file should look like -

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function () {


this.Given(/^I launch the protractor demo page$/, function () {
   return browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    });
});

this.When(/^I check the title of the page$/, function () {
   return browser.getTitle().then(function(text){
       console.log('title is - ' + text);
        expect(text).to.equal('Super Calculator');
    });

});
```

Comment: When I try to use the return function like `return browser.get('http://google.com');` it still fails with a timeout error. I've also tried it with a `.then` afterwards with a `callback` which times out as well.

Comment: ok i think your page takes more than the default time of 5000 ms of the steps that is why you are getting timeout error.did you try increasing the default time?

Comment: I've tried up to a minute. I see the page load, although nothing happens.

Comment: are you using angular or non-angular app?

Comment: angular app, but I've tested it also just on google.com

Comment: It is strange but nevertheless can you tell me which protractor , angular versions are you using? you would have to use `browser.ignoreSynchronization` with google.com

Comment: setting `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` seemed to fix the problem

Comment: glad it worked! you have to always use that setting for non-angular apps

Comment: for angular apps, how do you specify the wait time for the angular synchronization?

Comment: you don't have to wait actually, see that is what protractor does internally when it deals with angular apps. If you still explicitly want to wait then you could use ` browser.waitForAngular()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121197/discussion-between-user3554664-and-igniteram1).